# How to apply a texture to an object made using extrusion

Tags: html, x3d

I can apply without problems a texture to an object made using `indexedfaceset` but when i try to apply a texture to an object made using `extrusion` its like the faces of the object are not there. Example:

[image]  [image]

figure on the left is the result applying normal colors, and on the right applying the texture.

Here is the code when applying the textures:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Castle</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='x3dom-full.js'>
    </script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='x3dom.css' />
</head>
<body>
<x3d width="512px" height="512px">
    <scene>
        <switch whichChoice="-1">
            <extrusion id="wall" convex="true"
                       crossSection="
                      -1 -0.5
                      -0.7 -0.4
                      -0.4 -0.35
                      0 -0.3
                      0.4 -0.35
                      0.7 -0.4
                      1 -0.5
                      1 0.2
                      0.7 0.3
                      0.4 0.35
                      0 0.4
                      -0.4 0.35
                      -0.7 0.3
                      -1 0.2
                      -1 -0.5"
                       spine="
                       0 -1 0
                       0 0 0"
                       scale="
                       1 1
                       1 1">
            </extrusion>
        </switch>
        <transform translation="0 0 0" scale="1 1 1">
            <shape>
                <Appearance>
                    <ImageTexture url="castle_walls.jpg">
                    </ImageTexture>
                </Appearance>
                <x3dgeometrynode use="wall"></x3dgeometrynode>
            </shape>
        </transform>
    </scene>
</x3d>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Texture coordinates are automatically generated by Extrusion nodes. Textures are mapped so that the coordinates range in the U direction from 0 to 1 along the crossSection curve (with 0 corresponding to the first point in crossSection and 1 to the last) and in the V direction from 0 to 1 along the spine curve (with 0 corresponding to the first listed spine point and 1 to the last). If either the endCap or beginCap exists, the crossSection curve is uniformly scaled and translated so that the larger dimension of the cross-section (X or Z) produces texture coordinates that range from 0.0 to 1.0. The beginCap and endCap textures' S and T directions correspond to the X and Z directions in which the crossSection coordinates are defined.